# jquery navigation menu similar to home depot or amazon

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, navigation

Anyone know how i can create a jquery menu on wordpress same as the one found in home depot or amazon. the menu found on the left just under shop by department? 
is there something very similar for wordpress:- for example a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

While you've specified jQuery in your question, you don't need any javascript at all; you can do it in pure css, like **http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/menus/demo.html** and http://www.noupe.com/css/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html show.

There are many sites which allow you to design your own menu and download the code, like

- http://www.cssmenumaker.com/,
- http://purecssmenu.com/, or
- more at http://www.google.com/search?q=css+menu

Comment: I think you are mostly correct, Stobor. You are right that to do menus with animation like tabbed-dropdown menus or something like amazon's menu you could do it with css only. The main problem with css-only approaches is that they have annoying constraints such as the inability to have delays on the hover and mouse out events. Well maybe css3 has resolves those constraints, but many devs such as myself aren't able utilize lots of css3 awesomeness because we still have to deal with browsers that don't support it. So my experience is that css-only menues can be a little too jumpy for my tastes.

Comment: @shaune: Fair enough... Both the examples mentioned (amazon, home depot) don't use such things, or other animations, so I didn't think they were relevant. You're right that if you wish to animate the menus, something in javascript is necessary. Something like Superfish might be helpful to bridge the gap, though...

Comment: Stubor, yeah you are pretty much right and I thought your original answer was good, for sure.  The *only* point I still think I disagree with is that amazon does use some javascript in their main menu. To see what I am talking about simply hover over a menu item and then move your mouse down diagonally to the right.  You'll see that the popout on the right side of the menu doesn't change immediately like it does if you move your mouse down vertically. Very subtle, but very good for usability since the menu is "less jumpy". Not sure that can be done with css only. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @shaune: +1 Yeah, you're right; I didn't notice that. (I did go back to see if they had a hover delay or animations before I replied earlier, but I didn't notice that they had the diagonal movement protection.)